# Get SQL statement from a predicate?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

Is it possible to build the 'WHERE' clause of a SQL statement based on a predicate?

For example:

```
public override IQueryable<Customer> 
                    SearchFor(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate)
{ }
```

The base method just uses EF and all it does is:

```
return dbSet.Where(predicate);
```

However, in this particular scenario I need to override the method and, based on the predicate parameter, build a sql statement and execute that statement against the database directly (skipping EF).

So my new method would be:

```
public override IQueryable<Customer> SearchFor(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate)
{ 
    var where = predicate.ToString(); //Not actual code!!

    var sql = "SELECT id, name FROM customers WHERE " + where;
    //Execute sql statement
}
```

And the caller would do:

```
var customers = customerRepository.SearchFor(x => x.CustomerType = "ABC" && x.Age > 21);
```

The customer entity in this example is just an example. The reason for me to build an sql statement instead of using EF is:

1. Use Dapper for performance.
2. I will execute a stored procedure to fetch the reocrds.
3. The entities I'm using are not mapped to a table. A table exists in the database but these entities are just placeholder POCO's for when retrieving records.

Is it possible?

Comment: you can use custorm expression for predicate, can you explain what you want? possibly code sample?

Comment: This sounds very much like an X-Y problem. You may want to explain why you need to capture SQL and run it directly, there may be a less "hack-ish" way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`DataContext.GetCommand Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx)

Per MSDN:

> Gets the information about SQL commands generated by LINQ to SQL.

This will get you the whole SQL, but some string manipulation will get you just the Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code to convert to SQL.

https://github.com/phnx47/MicroOrm.Dapper.Repositories - Include SqlGenerator

https://github.com/phnx47/MicroOrm.SqlGenerator

Example:

```
var account = accountsRepository.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id)
```

Generated:

```
SELECT Accounts.Id, Accounts.Name, FROM Accounts  WHERE Accounts.Id = @Id
```